# Intersection of two incomplete DFAs

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Let assume that I have the following two automata A1 and A2 :

[image: A1]
[image: A2]

I have to do the **intersection** of the two, so I did this :

[image]

My question is related to the "∅". If I have two incomplete automata without dead states, and given a specific state, one automaton has a transition for one symbol but the second doesn't have it, what should I do ?
For example I am in the state 13 in the transition table and I read "b", should I rather put ∅ or 4 and make it non final ?

Comment: Try adding a dead state to both automata and then removing all dead stares from the product automaton.

Comment: I did it and I found the same result. Does this mean that it is acceptable to put ∅ directly when I have to deal with two incomplete automata where one has a transition but not the other ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it’s the only valid definition.

Comment: @Spn, [write your own answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, there are two different manners to solve this.

1. By adding a dead state whenever you have an incomplete automata. By doing so, you will no longer have to worry about what to do if one automata has a transition from a specific state but not the other.
2. You can still do the intersection of the two without adding dead states.

[image: automata]

In this example, if you are focusing on the state 1 and 3 with the symbol 'b' :
- From A1, you have no transition : δ(1,b) = ∅
- From A2, you have a transition : δ(3,b) = 4

Since one has a transition, but not the other, then the resulting automata will have the transition : δ(13,b) = ∅. Therefore, it is indeed acceptable to put ∅.